# The configuration Option for a column is not unique error - sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

I have a table with 5 columns. regionId is the primary key. One of the columns, regionKey, is a sql_variant type.

```
Create Table #Region
(
regionId int identity(1,1),
regionName varchar(100),
regionKey sql_variant,
CreationDate datetime,
ModifiedDate datetime
)

Insert Into #Region values ('South','123',getdate(),getdate())
Insert Into #Region values ('North','234',getdate(),getdate())
Insert Into #Region values ('East','123',getdate(),getdate())
```

When I try to enter the same value for the regionKey column for different regionIds, I get the following error:

> 'The configuration option (of the sql variant column) is not unique.'

I tried to see if there are any unique constraints defined but I couldn't find any. I tried looking online for this error but couldn't find anything. Could someone please explain what this is?

Note: You won't see the error in the temp table that I posted above. The error only happens on our server since they have some configurations that I don't understand.

Comment: _You won't see the error in the temp table_ Then we can't help you. A [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=2244e1c7ad4d8b0f044e65e4a40d21a5) runs without issue - so your problem must lie elsewhere. Perhaps start asking others in your organization for help. And stop the lazy coding. Always specify a column list for your insert statement. And seriously reconsider the use of sql_variant - that will only lead to more issues.

Comment: Are there ay triggers on the table?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Yes, there is a trigger on the table.

Comment: Well, the problem seems to be related to configurations - which is a system wide related feature. If your insert triggers more inserts or updates to other (possibly system) tables, you may get this error (I believe the error code is 15124 for `'The configuration option (of the %s column) is not unique.'` error.) You'll need to check what the triggers do and/or find documentation / ask others in your organization about the structure/design of the database.